# window as RootViewController with Navigation Controller upon it

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:windowObj];

Can i do this?
Making a window as RootViewController with Navigation Controller upon it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-initWithRootViewController: takes an UIViewController as its argument. Passing an UIWindow instance instead won't work. You can however use the view of the navigation controller as your applications main view.